# CSS grid layout without predetermining number of columns for each cell

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

Grid with 6 columns. Each column of the grid is 50px

```
Content 1: <section><p>hello</p></section>
Content 2: <section><img width="110"></section>
Content 3: <section><p>goodbye</p></section>
Content 4: <section><img width="250"></section>
Content 5: <section><img width="65"></section>
```

I'd like this content to somehow know to layout as follows without being "told" how many columns each piece of content takes up:

```
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|          |                                |          |
| hello    | 110px-wide image               | goodbye  |
|          |                                |          |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|                                                      |
| 200px-wide image
|                                                      |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|                     |
| 65px-wide image     |
|                     |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Is there any way in any fairly-widely-supported CSS to set up a grid that does this without attaching any col-x type class or explicit width to each section element?

Example of something I tried with flexbox but I'm not sure how to tell it "the grid columns are 50px wide and there are 6 of them":

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: space-between;
    align-content: center;
}
section {
    border: 1px black solid;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 6;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <section><p>hello</p></section>
  <section><img src="http://comefillyourcup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/2880x1800-bright-ube-solid-color-background-128x128.jpg" width="110"></section>
  <section><p>goodbye</p></section>
  <section><img src="https://i.imgur.com/WgbsUUv.png" width="250"></section>
  <section><img src="https://i.imgur.com/SUl31R3.png" width="65"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: flex looks more efficient here than grid ... You should share your html and css to show your issue

Comment: Good point. Minimal example coming up ...

Comment: Added the HTML that I'd like to layout as per the ASCII diagram. Not sure what CSS to add – that's the question! :)

Comment: okay, have you done any attempt with flex or grid that did not worked ?

Comment: Added something to the code snippet that I tried earlier. Flexbox does wonderful things but I couldn't work out how to tell it "hey, there are 6 columns just use them as you need to to put this stuff in". Possibly because it can't do that :)

Comment: grid would be the one then, but you will have to tell children how many columns they span.

Comment: There's no such thing as "my grid is this size, please fit it", then? I was kind of coming to that conclusion but I thought I would ask the experts. Perhaps I can hide everything, detect widths in javascript, and then show once I've aligned everything. Quite icky but sounds like it would work.

Comment: you could use grid, class and grid-auto-flow:dense to fill gaps as much as possible  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MOyEqv

Comment: That is pretty cool. I still have to tell the bigger content that they are col-2 and col-6 though. If I don't know that until runtime (it's dynamic content) am I out of luck?

Comment: you can dispatch the class at runtime according to their width. (example ,absolute position and hidden at first to retrieve the width it takes .. then give the classname and remove the position/hidden visibility ;)

Comment: I think it's either going to be that or give up on my grid dreams. Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make `section` inline-block like this :

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <section>
    <p>hello</p>
  </section>
  <section><img src="http://coschedule.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/linkedin-recommended-image-sizes-770x884.png" width="410"></section>
  <section>
    <p>goodbye</p>
  </section>
  <section><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_w0r3cYUSD7A/Sob415afOVI/AAAAAAAABa4/-J_vkiTkITE/s1600/sunflare.jpg" width="1000"></section>
  <section><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Wide%2C_Samuel_1892.jpg/200px-Wide%2C_Samuel_1892.jpg" width="250"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!

Am I right in thinking that if I change the order of the boxes this won't work at all? I'm trying to avoid predefining how many columns/% any given content box takes up and just have it "snap to grid".

I want it to work exactly like a gridless page only each box should somehow be told "you must end up being some multiple of 100px wide" and also "if you go past the end of the row, wrap under".

It may well be that this is not possible :)

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker in this case we can use fixed width, i use % in order to keep the responsive, but we can switch to fixed value

Comment: Thanks! We are saying here that the fourth item in the grid is 500px wide. That's what I want to avoid. This content would be dynamic and could be anything from 1px to 1200px wide. Does that make sense?

Comment: So in this case you may simply make all the sections `inline-block` and you will obtain what you need as all of them will expand as per their content

Comment: Ah, that would be good. Will they then expand/fill the space to the right of themselves so that the stuff beyond would still respect the grid? That's the part I can't figure out.

Comment: Sorry I'm not being very clear. In my hoped-for version the "hello" and "goodbye" columns would both take up one full column of the grid and be the same size as each other.

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker am getting confused :s ... if you want them to take a column or two you have to simply specify it and if you want them to be free and expand the space simply leave them with no specification. I am not sure i understand what you need

Comment: I want them to be free and expand BUT also respect the grid. So they can take up 100, 200, 300, but not 240 or 27. I think it's not possible without javascript :(

Comment: Ah ok, so it's like you want to round the width to the nearest value that is multiple of Column width ? is a JS solution ok with your need, i can provide you one

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's a much clearer way to put it! I think I can manage the js version – I was just hoping there was something in grid or flexbox that was going to make it unnecessary!

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker when it come to **dynamicly** resize content i think you won't be able to find a pure CSS solution